# unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) in your code for wordpress single post template

Tags: php, reference, wordpress-theming

```
// Post taxonomies
                                        if( $options[ 'elements' ][ 'categories' ] || $options[ 'elements' ][ 'professions' ] ) || $options[ 'elements' ][ 'badges' ] ) {
                                            boombox_get_template_part( 'template-parts/single/components/taxonomy', '', array(
                                                'categories' => $options[ 'elements' ][ 'categories' ],
                                                'professions' => $options[ 'elements' ][ 'professions' ],
                                                'badges'     => $options[ 'elements' ][ 'badges' ]
                                            ) );
                                        }
```

It says unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) in your code on line 1, Then what will be correct code?

Comment: The `if(` ends at `) || $options[ ` so the `||` is outside the if.

Comment: Always count the opening en closing parenthesis.

Comment: Solved. Thank you for the correction.